# linux terminal page up and page down in C program

Tags: c, linux, terminal

How do we call the (shift + pageup) and (shift + pagedown) functions, for linux terminal, from within a C program using any other keys (e.g, up down arrows). What system calls do I need to make.

Comment: That's not part of the console, that's part of the terminal *program*, which is a completely separate progrma handling the terminal windows and which also means it's not directly controllable and especially not by system calls. There are some [VT100](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) escape sequences for [scrolling](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm#scroll), if that might help.

Comment: seems useful but how do I implement them

Comment: The given "VT100" link is notable mostly for being inaccurate - see [http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color]

Answer (score 1):

Those features are manipulated by sending *escape sequences*, i.e., sequences of characters (usually beginning with the "escape" character) to the terminal.

The detailed sequences for the Linux console are documented in the [console_codes](http://linux.die.net/man/4/console_codes) manual page. However, every terminal emulator (for instance, any terminal program which you run in a desktop environment) differs from that.  Some are documented ([xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) and rxvt), others are not (gnome-terminal, konsole).

Most refer to themselves as VT100-like, for the DEC VT100 terminal.  Here are sources of information at opposite ends of the scale

- [VT100.net](http://vt100.net/) (informative)
- [ANSI/VT100 Terminal Control Escape Sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) (inaccurate, as noted in the ncurses FAQ [How do I get color with VT100?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color)

To provide a better programmatic interface to these features, there are libraries ([ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html) and slang), using a terminal database (listing what is provided by a given terminal, and how to do it).

From the command-line, shell scripts can use the [tput](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/tput.1.html) program to send escape sequences.  (It is common for shell scripts to just hardcode these as well, at the expense of lack of portability and readability).

Comment: Thankyou everyone for you help, I will give ncurses library a try

Comment: scrolling up and down in ncurses only moves the window does not display the previous text.

Comment: You can use a "pad" to manage larger areas than fit into a window.

Comment: I'm sorry I could not find anything on pad. Although I was able to accomplish the task using ncurses but If "pad" offers a better solution, I will be happy to give it a try

Comment: "pads" are a feature of curses -- see http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_pad.3x.html